# Android Writing/Reading Picture To Internal Storage

Tags: android, image, fileoutputstream

I faced a problem saving and loading Pictures on android (Picture object). Here is my code for writing to Internal Storage (i am not sure if it works properly):

```java
FileOutputStream fos = null;
Picture l0 = new Picture();
fos = openFileOutput("layer0", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(layer0.getBytes());
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(is);
l0 = svg.getPicture();
                
l0.writeToStream(fos);
fos.close();
```

How can I read this image back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [createFromStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html#createFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)

Something like:

```
Picture myPic = Picture.createFromStream(openFileInput("layer0"));
```